# How to install pywhatkit in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

[if I am going to install pywhatkit in the shell, it is showing some error. How to install it in the right way. I am using Thonny.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCOrM.png)

Comment: You are running pip on a Python shell (or REPL). That generates a SyntaxError. To install something, run `pip install [PACKAGE_TO_INSTALL]` outside this shell. For example, on a command prompt or bash.

Comment: Also, please don't use screenshots for code, inputs and outputs. Instead, use `formatted code`.

Answer (score 0):

To install any python library just use `pip install <library_name>` (or `pip3 install <library_name>` on linux or mac devices.)

In your case it is `pip install pywhatkit`.

If these don't work try `pip3 install pywhatkit`. (For a mac or linux device.)

If this also doesn't work try `python -m pip install pywhatkit` or `python3 -m pip install pywhatkit`.

If none of them work, the best option would be reinstalling python to its latest version and also make sure to **add python to path**.
[This is a sample image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09HdF.png)

Note: Some libraries don't work with